# Trouble reading from xml file to textboxes and comboboxes

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I have used some code a couple times in testing and it seems to work well.  Now I am working on a helper app for a game and trying to apply the same code, but it is failing.  I need to know if there is some error I am overlooking.  I am trying to read from an xml file and populate text boxes and combo boxes in my winform.  I pull the name correctly, but the remaining attributes do not populate.  Here is an example of my code:

```
public bool LoadChar(string _filename) //Fetches character stats from xml file and loads to the textboxes
    {
        try
        {
            _name = tbName.Text;//hero                    
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();//hero                    
            doc.Load(_filename);//hero
            XmlNode _currNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Characters/Char[@name='" + _name + "']");//hero                    

            _currNode.Attributes["st"].Value = _st;
            _currNode.Attributes["dx"].Value = _dx;
            _currNode.Attributes["iq"].Value = _iq;
            _currNode.Attributes["ma"].Value = _ma;
            _currNode.Attributes["armor"].Value = _armor;
            _currNode.Attributes["hits"].Value = _hits;
            _currNode.Attributes["wounds"].Value = _wounds;
            _currNode.Attributes["fatigue"].Value = _fatigue;
            _currNode.Attributes["attack"].Value = _attack;
            _currNode.Attributes["dmgdie"].Value = _dmgdie;
            _currNode.Attributes["dmgmod"].Value = _dmgmod;
            _currNode.Attributes["exp"].Value = _exp;
            _currNode.Attributes["description"].Value = _description;
            _currNode.Attributes["equipment_money"].Value = _equipmentmoney;
            _currNode.Attributes["weapons_armor"].Value = _wpnarmor;
            _currNode.Attributes["talents_spells"].Value = _talentspell;
            _currNode.Attributes["gender"].Value = _gender;
            _currNode.Attributes["race"].Value = _race;
            _currNode.Attributes["type"].Value = _type;
            _currNode.Attributes["job"].Value = _job;


            tbName.Text = _name;
            tbSt.Text = _st;
            tbDx.Text = _dx;
            tbIq.Text = _iq;
            tbMa.Text = _ma;
            tbArmor.Text = _armor;
            tbHitStop.Text = _hits;
            tbWounds.Text = _wounds;
            tbFatigue.Text = _fatigue;
            tbAttack.Text = _attack;
            tbDmgDie.Text = _dmgdie;
            tbDmgMod.Text = _dmgmod;
            tbExp.Text = _exp;
            tbDescription.Text = _description;
            tbEquipmentMoney.Text = _equipmentmoney;
            tbWeaponArmor.Text = _wpnarmor;
            tbTalentSpell.Text = _talentspell;
            cbGender.SelectedValue = _gender;
            cbRace.SelectedValue = _race;
            cbType.SelectedValue = _type;
            cbJob.SelectedValue = _job;


            return true;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is the xml file I am attempting to get the data from:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <Characters>
  <Char name="Conan" st="15" dx="13" iq="8" ma="10" armor="Leather" hits="2" wounds="2"     
fatigue="0" attack="Great Sword" dmgdie="3" dmgmod="+2" exp="69" description="Conan is a 
big enthusiastic gentleman" equipment_money="Backpack, 4 gold coins." 
weapons_armor="Great Sword, Longbow." talents_spells="Killing, Maiming, Strangling, 
Boxing, Florist." gender="Male" race="Human" type="Barbarian" job="Unskilled" /> 
  </Characters>
```

I created the xml file by writing the textboxes and comboboxes in my form to the xml, but now I want to load a character from the xml and it is not working in this example.  I do have it working in another example and I have compared the two closely together, but can not find any real differences besides this example having more and different attributes.

Note: I placed a breakpoint and the _name value pulls "Conan" but all other values are null.

I intend to refine this later at some point--just bashing it out right now.

Comment: @Downvoter, sorry forgot to list my research links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not loading data from XML. To read data you need to change places like this:

```
 public bool LoadChar(string _filename) //Fetches character stats from xml file and loads to the textboxes
 {
     try
     {
        _name = tbName.Text;//hero                    
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();//hero                    
        doc.Load(_filename);//hero
        XmlNode _currNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("/Characters/Char[@name='" + _name + "']");//hero 

        //reading attributes values  
        _st = _currNode.Attributes["st"].Value;
        _dx = _currNode.Attributes["dx"].Value;
        _iq = _currNode.Attributes["iq"].Value;
        _ma = _currNode.Attributes["ma"].Value;
        _armor = _currNode.Attributes["armor"].Value;
        _hits = _currNode.Attributes["hits"].Value;
        _wounds = _currNode.Attributes["wounds"].Value;
        _fatigue = _currNode.Attributes["fatigue"].Value;
        _attack = _currNode.Attributes["attack"].Value;
        _dmgdie = _currNode.Attributes["dmgdie"].Value;
        _dmgmod = _currNode.Attributes["dmgmod"].Value;
        _exp = _currNode.Attributes["exp"].Value;
        _description = _currNode.Attributes["description"].Value;
        _equipmentmoney = _currNode.Attributes["equipment_money"].Value;
        _wpnarmor = _currNode.Attributes["weapons_armor"].Value;
        _talentspell = _currNode.Attributes["talents_spells"].Value;
        _gender = _currNode.Attributes["gender"].Value;
        _race = _currNode.Attributes["race"].Value;
        _type = _currNode.Attributes["type"].Value;
        _job = _currNode.Attributes["job"].Value;


        tbName.Text = _name;
        tbSt.Text = _st;
        tbDx.Text = _dx;
        tbIq.Text = _iq;
        tbMa.Text = _ma;
        tbArmor.Text = _armor;
        tbHitStop.Text = _hits;
        tbWounds.Text = _wounds;
        tbFatigue.Text = _fatigue;
        tbAttack.Text = _attack;
        tbDmgDie.Text = _dmgdie;
        tbDmgMod.Text = _dmgmod;
        tbExp.Text = _exp;
        tbDescription.Text = _description;
        tbEquipmentMoney.Text = _equipmentmoney;
        tbWeaponArmor.Text = _wpnarmor;
        tbTalentSpell.Text = _talentspell;
        cbGender.SelectedValue = _gender;
        cbRace.SelectedValue = _race;
        cbType.SelectedValue = _type;
        cbJob.SelectedValue = _job;


        return true;
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your eye on this.  I knew it would be something simple.  I was copying code I had used earlier and this was from the wrong method.

Comment: Also had to change `code`combobox.SelectedValue = _variable;`code` to `code` combobox.Text = _variable;`code` for all my comboboxes.